# What is Gallium? "Gallium 0.4 on AMD"

Tags: drivers, 13.04

I have laptop using ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4640 video controller. I know there is an issue with official AMD drivers in 12.10 and 12.04 and problems with legacy drivers, but I tried to see if these are fixed in 13.04

So i installed fresh copy of 13.04 and found under system:

**Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV730**

First time i've seen this...

`lshw -c display` gives this information:

```
description: VGA compatible controller
   product: M96 [Mobility Radeon HD 4650]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
   resources: irq:49 memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:cfef0000-cfefffff memory:cfe00000-cfe1ffff
```

What is it? Is my driver working normally or is it some kind of bug? What is Gallium?

Answer (score 8):

Gallium is the OPEN SOURCE DRIVER as ATI does not make more legacy drivers for our "old" architecture

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. I understand that they are OSD but they wont have same effect as legacy drivers had in earlier versions of Ubuntu. For example - lesser stresslevel e.g. smaller fan-spin